# PHP not inserting data into MYSQLi

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I tried a little program to insert data in mysql through PHP but nothing happens. It neither gives an error nor it is inserting the data. Unable to understand where is the problem?

```
<?php
$database=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","aaa")or die('Localhost Connection Problem');
$xyz=mysqli_select_db($database,"aaa");
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
    $dlqty=$_POST['dlqty'];
    $slqty=$_POST['slqty'];
    $price=$_POST['price'];
$ins=mysqli_query($database,"insert into bbb (dlqty,slqty,price) values ('$dlqty','$slqty','$price')");
mysqli_close($database);
}
?>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>

<body>
<form name="eee" method="post">
<input type="text" name="dlqty"  />
<input type="text" name="slqty"  />
<input type="text" name="price"  />
<input type="button" name="submit" value="submit" />
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Help will be appreciated.

Comment: Do you get any errors or warnings ?

Comment: The only way to show those errors is to modify your php.ini with this line:

display_errors = on

Comment: Nothing, no error and not inserting

Comment: **display_errors = on** is already done

Comment: Attentiom! If you manage to make this code run, it is very dangerous. You directly use the server-variables for sql, this is highly related to sql injection. It is very easy to attack your website an doete your data, modify your database, etc.

Comment: in if statement block write echo "insert into bbb (dlqty,slqty,price) values ('$dlqty','$slqty','$price')"); Its for checking that executed sql and print the sql text

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a HTML problem. Your form actually doesn't submit anything.

Change your submit button definition from

```
<input type="button" name="submit" value="submit" />
```

to

```
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit" />
```

Comment: YOU ROCK DUDE. You solved the issue. Silly mistake by me.

Comment: Glad I could help. Have fun coding further. ;-)

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
$query = "
INSERT INTO bbb (dlqty,slqty,price) VALUES ('$dlqty','$slqty','$price');
";

$ins = mysqli_query($database,$query) or die(mysqli_error());
```

And then, once you've figured out the problem, switch to prepared statements